# Post data to controller from another controller

Tags: node.js, express, controller

The below code is from a controller in my backend. I am using node and express

The if statement sends data from stripe api to the frontend to be validated before payment is complete.

This is a requirement for taking payments in the EU.

When the payment is confirmed, the front end posts to the backend and runs the code in a controller named emailTickets.

When I am selling free tickets there is no need for stripe so I want to post data to the controller named emailTickets from the else statement (this is contained in a different controller in the backend)

How do I do this?

```
            if(numTicketsSought.find(e => e.chargeForTicketsStatus === 'chargeForTicket')!==undefined){
                stripeRes = data[2]
                res.send(response)
            }else{

              //i want to call another controller here

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
 res.redirect(308, "/test/" + testID) // example
```

Which will preserve the send method.

For reference, the 308 http code spec is:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 308 Permanent Redirect redirect status > > response code indicates that the resource requested has been definitively moved > to the URL given by the Location headers. A browser redirects to this page and > search engines update their links to the resource (in 'SEO-speak', it is said > > that the 'link-juice' is sent to the new URL).

For more info, see: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/redirect

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm trying to post data to another controller in the backend. The examples in the docs are for redirecting to websites and websites

Comment: Do you want to POST to different controllers of the same server?

Comment: Yes...in the else condition I want to post data to a different back end controller. Note, the else condition is in a different back end controller